# Password Not updating in database

Tags: php, email, mysqli

I created a function called password_reset

My recover_password page works perfect and sends the email and updates a field called validation_code as I expect it to.

Now when I get the email it sends this link

To reset your password, please visit 
`http://localhost/cms/account/reset-password.php?email=myemail.net&code=313893625577`

now I have a page called `reset-password.php` as you see in the link

when you click on it goes to the page perfectly

my html

```
 <?php display_message();?>
 <?php password_reset();?>

 <form role="form" action="reset-password.php" method="post">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label>Verification Code</label>
      <input class="form-control" type="text" id="verification_code"   name="verification_code" value="<?php echo isset($_GET['code']) ? $_GET['code'] : '';?>">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label>Email Address</label>
      <input class="form-control" type="text" id="email" name="email" value="<?php echo isset($_GET['email']) ? $_GET['email'] : '';?>">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label>Password</label>
      <input class="form-control" type="text" id="password" name="password" placeholder="Password">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label>Confirm New Password</label>
      <input class="form-control" type="text" id="confirm_password" name="confirm_password" placeholder="Confirm Password">
    </div>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" id="btn-login" class="btn btn-custom btn-lg btn-block" value="Reset Password">
  <input type="hidden" class="hide" name="token" id="token" value="<?php echo token_generator();?>">

  </form>
```

I used

```
value="<?php echo isset($_GET['code']) ? $_GET['code'] : '';?>"> 
value="<?php echo isset($_GET['email']) ? $_GET['email'] : '';?>">
```

to pull the values from the url and put into the fields... the problem is that it will not update the passwords when you type in the new passwords

I have 4 fields on the the reset page

validation code
email
password
confirm_password

now when I put the passwords in I click submit it it does not update the password.

```
function password_reset()
{
    if (isset($_COOKIE['temp_access_code'])) {

        if (isset($_POST['email']) && isset($_POST['code'])) {

            if (isset($_SESSION['token']) && isset($_POST['token'])) {

                if ($_POST['token'] === $_SESSION['token']) {

                    if ($_POST['password'] === $_POST['confirm_password']) {

                         $updated_password = password_hash($_POST['password']);

                        $sql = "UPDATE users SET user_pwd = '" . escape($updated_password) . "', validation_code = 0 WHERE user_email = '" . escape($_GET['email']) . "'";
                        query($sql);

                        set_message("your password was updated");

                }
            }
        }
    }
    } else {

        set_message("Sorry your time has expired");
        redirect("../account/request-password-reset.php");
    }
}// End Function
```

here is what it looks like when you click the link given in the email

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your function `password_reset()` you are using the check

`if (isset($_GET['email']) && isset($_GET['code'])) {`

but it will never be true because you are sending the form with post, so you need to check for

```
if (isset($_POST['email']) && isset($_POST['code'])) {
```

to get further in your function.

Comment: Thank you for your reply I have tried that but get the same result

Comment: The errors are obvious, you are sendung the form via post, and request the GET Parameters. You should change the two lines with `<?php echo $_GET['email'];` with `<?php echo isset($_GET['email']) ? $_GET['email'] : '';` That should take care of the errors, but the not-saving is not affected by that.

Comment: I have made edits to the code as you have suggested how ever the form seems to function it does not update password or display set_message("your password was updated"); or redirect

Comment: In your function `password_reset()` you are checking for the POST variable `code` which does not exist. The correct name is `verification_code`. You should check, which variables are submitted by using `var_dump($_GET,$_POST,$_COOKIE);`.